# Django How do I filter querysets to insersect common results

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset

I want to filter a queryset that depends on another queryset

My models.py

```
class Escola(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='Nome', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Inscrio(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    escolaid = models.ForeignKey(Escola, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='EscolaID', blank=True, null=True)
```

This is my views.py

```
def view_forms(request):
   return render(request, 
                 "main/view_forms.html", 
                 {"escolas": Escola.objects.all,
                 })
```

I have an .html template where I run a for loop to write all the objects of Escola and those objects are connected with the Model Inscrio (by 'escolaid' foreign key).

I want a queryset to find Inscrio objects that have the same 'escolaid' as Escola's 'id'

For example, say the for loop returned the 'id' = 1 for the model Escola, now I want to get (in a for loop) all Inscrio objects with 'escolaid' = 1 and I want this until the Escola loop has no more values

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### simple in the template, and if you assigned a related_name(exp: `inscrios`) for escolaid in Inscrio Model, `escola.inscrio_set` should be replaced as `escola.inscrios`. Go through the document: [related-objects-reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.2/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)

```
{% for escola in escolas %}
  {# handle escola #}

  {% for inscrio in escola.inscrio_set %}
    {# handle inscrio #}
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```